# How to serve static files in Django development

Tags: django, file, static

Here is the directory structure pf project.

```
mysite
  \media
  \static
       \images
       \css
           base.css
       \js 
  \templates
       base.html
  \settings.py #and other .py files
```

Now say if i have a file `C:\mysite\static\css\base.css` or an image `C:\mysite\static\images\ball.png` .How am i going to serve it using django development server. I know this is not the recomment way, but just in development i want this to work. I have read the docs and other answers on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. May be i am being confused by `media` and `static` and `urlpatterns`. I have spent hours trying to figure this out but still no luck. 
I am new to django and all this seems to me just an overkill to get a css or image showing up.
What changes or editing do i need to make for this to work. How will i referece the image and css in template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the how to for static files from the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) that takes you through the whole process step-by-step.

Add the following to your urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Then 'This view is automatically enabled and will serve your static files at STATIC_URL when you use the built-in runserver management command. ... This will inspect your STATIC_URL setting and wire up the view to serve static files accordingly. Don't forget to set the STATICFILES_DIRS setting appropriately to let django.contrib.staticfiles know where to look for files additionally to files in app directories.'

It is worth mentioning that this is most definitely inappropriate for deployment, but will work well for development.

Comment: +1 for the documentation link. It works great.I don't know where that link was when i was pulling my hairs out.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're not supposed to manually put anything in `STATIC_ROOT`. It's only a dumping ground for the `collectstatic` management command in production, and is supposed to be served by your webserver.

In development, Django *automatically* serves anything in your apps' "static" directories and any folder in `STATICFILES_DIR`. If you have project-wide static resources, you need to create an entirely separate folder, different than both `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` and add that to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. I usually call it "assets", but it's name doesn't matter.

Comment: @jvc26's answer did the work. +1 for _"It's only a dumping ground for the collectstatic management command in production"_

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the full path to `media` and `static` to [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs) in settings.py
2. Make sure `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings.py has `'django.core.context_processors.static',` in there. *Its there by default.*
3. Use `{{ STATIC_URL }}images/ball.png` in your templates.

Comment: The reason this answers the question is that in development (runserver), static files are served **automatically** via `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: No, no, no, no, and... wait for it... no. Do *not* add `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. The problem here is that Django doesn't serve STATIC_ROOT, *intentionally*.

Comment: No one is talking about `STATIC_ROOT`. The question is simply 'how do I serve files from a directory using development server'.

Comment: And that's *not* how you do it. Read the docs. Or, more appropriate, I guess, that's not how you serve the items in `media` or `static`. That's the point.

Comment: `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is rendering empty and see no errors. However thanks for your attention.May be i didn't explain myself well enough.

Comment: Sir, your solution indeed works but i have to add `from django.template import RequestContext` in my views.py file becasue i was using `render_to_response()`. here is the render code `render_to_response('base.html',{'dev':True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`. I just added `context_instance` (as said by docs) and it worked.