# Highcharts in django

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts, django-templates

I am new to django. I want to use highcharts in django to plot graphs. What I did is I created a project named Telecom. Then I put the highcharts file inside the folder Telecom/media/highcharts. And I write a file script.js in the location Telecom/media/js.

**script.js**

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                    'Jan',
                    'Feb',
                    'Mar',
                    'Apr',
                    'May',
                    'Jun',
                    'Jul',
                    'Aug',
                    'Sep',
                    'Oct',
                    'Nov',
                    'Dec'
                ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            }]
        });
    });
```

Also 
**Telecom/templates/welcome/higraph.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:50%; height:400px; float:right;">
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)


MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'telecom_db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'UTC'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'..', 'media')

MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'b9_hyqe*b&ra_&wlm5a9xas_ag#5mjv-dy=to%hdk_u-#xvn*l'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (       
                  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..','templates'),
#                  os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates/welcome'),
)


MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Telecom.urls'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.admin',

    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'welcome',
)

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

But the graph is not displaying, How to make it work ?

Comment: [djangoproject.com/howto/serve-static-files/](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serve static files in Django development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612578/how-to-serve-static-files-in-django-development) and many other SO posts

Comment: I have tried with those links but cannot find the solution, please help in my context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program need internet to display the graph as .js file location is from url. If you want to load graph offline then download required library (js file) and make some change like below.

settings.py #update static root and url

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Now place your .js (source file) inside the static folder which is created inside your app folder.

Now in template load `.js` file by putting below code inside header tag.

```
{% load staticfiles %}    
    <script src="{% static "js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/script.js" %}"></script>
```

Here I placed sample js library in directory location like `/my_app/static/js/...` So on src you need to give location after static folder. Hope you will able to display the graph after following this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this will help you:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SETTINGS_FILE_PATH = os.path.realpath(__file__)

SETTINGS_DIR = os.path.dirname(SETTINGS_FILE_PATH)

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(SETTINGS_DIR)

MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_DIR,
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
    )
```